# How to plot the function expanded in a series

Tags: series-expansion

Suppose some function f[x,y]. I want to expand it in series, like

```
g[x_,y_] = Series[f[x,y], {y,0,2}]
```

After that I need to plot the graphic of $g$. But it is impossible because of `O[y^2]` term in the expression for g.

How to throw out this `O[y^2]` term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose use `Normal`,

```
f[x_, y_] = Exp[x*y]

g[x_, y_] = Normal@Series[f[x, y], {y, 0, 2}]
```

> 1 + x y + (x^2 y^2)/2

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```